# How to reflow HighCharts when using highcharts-vue?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, highcharts, vuejs2

I've got a pretty simple component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <chart
            v-if="!loading"
            ref="priceGraph"
            constructor-type="stockChart"
            :options="chartData"
            :deepCopyOnUpdate="false"
        />
        <div v-else>Loading...</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { EventBus } from "../events";
import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue";
import { PriceData } from "src/models/DataFile";

@Component({
    components: { Chart }
})
export default class PriceChart extends Vue {
    @Prop({ type: Boolean, required: true })
    readonly loading!: boolean;

    @Prop({ type: Array, required: true })
    readonly prices!: PriceData;

    mounted() {
        EventBus.$on("reflow", () => {
            // NOT RIGHT:
            this.$refs.priceGraph.chart.reflow();
        });
    }

    get chartData() {
        return {
            xAxis: {},
            yAxis: {},
            series: [
                {
                    type: "candlestick",
                    data: this.prices
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

Per the [highcharts-vue documentation](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#chart-object-reference), it should be possible to access the underlying Highcharts instance so that I can call the [`reflow` method](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.reflow). However I'm having trouble figuring out how...

> You can access the Chart object instance if necessary (e.g when need to get some data or use any of Chart.prototype functions), **by calling specific Vue component instance chart field**, but it is not supported to update the chart using its built-in functions, because that could cause a problems with data synchronization between your app and the chart itself (it disturbs conception of using wrappers). The most recommended way of implementing it, is to use it in the way presented in demo app.

It's not 100% clear what is meant by "calling specific Vue component instance chart field", but I *assume* this means I can say `this.$refs.priceGraph.chart` to get the instance (the "chart" field of the Vue component instance, and my understanding is that `this.$refs.priceGraph` should refer to the Vue component instance)

But it's failing in two different ways. At compile-time I'm getting the following error from TypeScript:

```
ERROR in /home/stevenbarnett/Repos/stockgraph/src/components/PriceChart.vue(33,26):
TS2339: Property 'chart' does not exist on type 'Element | Element[] | Vue | Vue[]'.
  Property 'chart' does not exist on type 'Element'.
Version: typescript 3.9.5
```

If I ignore this error and run my code anyway, it's failing in the console saying that `this.$refs.priceGraph is undefined` (despite the Vue Dev Tools showing it's populated). See attached:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It suppose to work exactly as you described, so calling the `reflow` on `this.$refs.priceGraph.chart` should be pretty enough. One thing which comes to my mind here is that the chart component has the `v-if` property, which could somehow prevent the Vue to render it before calling `mounted` lifecycle hook, i mean the reference is not already available then. Could you reproduce the problem on some live demo? Here is a good start point, which shows that `reflow` can be called in the mentioned way: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-opvon

Comment: Regarding the Typescript error, we're aware that the wrapper can produce errors, because of the fact that the Vue v2 is a bit hard to handle in a typing meaning. We definitely need to work on the typings while updating the preparing the wrapper to work with v3.

Comment: I forked the demo you linked and attempted to recreate the basics of what I'm trying to do (https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-7sefk). I noticed that weirdly whenever I edit a file and it re-builds I start getting the console errors (even if I just make a tiny tweak to the CSS and don't touch the JavaScript). I have to refresh the whole whole editor (not just the mini-browser inside it) to get it working again. Even when working I'm getting the opposite of the desired behavior (chart is never the right size)

Comment: Thanks. The problem looks like the one of the Vue nature, because as the `this.toggle` classes for the component data are changing correctly, the class name for the reference containing element does not change immediately, and actually the `reflow()` method is called before real class change. The fastest way to avoid it, is to wrap the reflow method with `setTimeout` and call it with the 1ms delay, then it will work as you expected. Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-geclj?file=/src/components/Chart.vue

Comment: I'm going to guess that my issues with `_this.$refs.priceGraph is undefined` are related to the issue I saw in Code Sandbox where I had to refresh the page whenever I made a change. Maybe I need to clear my cache, restart VS Code, and rebuild my entire project. Would love a proper solution to my TypeScript issue, though, that doesn't involve sloppily adding `/* ts-ignore */` everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.$refs.priceGraph.chart.reflow();
});
```

This makes sure that the chart you reference is rendered.